# Paired comparisons algorithm design

Tags: algorithm

I have 15 groupings of 5 words. Let's say the first grouping is the 'happy' grouping and is the following: ["happy", "smile", "fun", "joy", "laugh"], and the second is the 'sad' grouping and is the following: ["sad", "frown", "bummer", "cry", "rain-cloud"]. All the other groupings are similar, with five words in an array.

I am designing a paired comparisons react app, and I need one word from each grouping to be randomly chosen and paired with a randomly chosen word from each other grouping. From the examples above, a pair for grouping 1 and 2 might be ["smile", "cry"]. There should be 120 total pairs (exactly one for each grouping with each other grouping).

I was thinking of using a loop and going through the groupings one by one, then for each of the remaining groupings, taking a random word from the grouping I'm looking at and one from the other and creating a pair.

I feel like this isn't very elegant or efficient, and I'm curious how I might design a better algorithm. I think recursion might be helpful, but I can't think of how I could use it in this scenario.

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there should be 120 pairs? I believe it's `binom(15, 2) = 105`.

Comment: Its right 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of populating intermediate arrays of indexes (sort of like indirect referencing). remove one from that at random. That way you never choose same option randomly again.

Comment: could you show an example with lower cardinalities? (say 3 groups, with two words in each group, and a possible set of pairings)

Answer (score 0):

I had a thought about using recursion, but unfortunately I couldn't think of any algorithm.

What I tried here is: while the list of all sets is not empty, iterate through every item on the first set, and pair it with a random item from any other set, then remove that chosen item. After the whole first set is iterated, simply remove that first set from the list of all sets. This way there is no need of extra calculation that checks for duplicates.

(I used javascript for implementing, and made the sets simpler)

```
let myArray = [["happy", "smile", "fun"],
               ["sad", "frown", "bummer"],
               [1,2,3],
               [4,5,6]]

let pairs = []

while (myArray.length != 1){    
    for (var i = 0; i<myArray[0].length; i++){
        var next = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (myArray.length-1)) + 1];
        var nextindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*next.length)

        pairs.push([myArray [0][i], next[nextindex]]);
        next.splice(nextindex, 1)
    }
    anarray.splice(0, 1);
}

console.log(pairs)
```

Although, as you said, this code is not elegant (nor the most efficient)... There should be a better solution, so it is worth it to keep on thinking for a better algorithm!